# Excel VBA Copy Table, Paste Values in new sheet

Tags: excel, copy-paste, paste, vba

I'm working on taking values entered into a Table in one sheet, and pasting the values into a different sheet on subsequent rows, so that each time someone enters data into the table and runs the macro a new line will populate in the database. The macro I'm working with pastes the cells with the Table's formatting. Is there an easy way to augment the below code to paste just the values?

Thanks!

```
Sub copyRow()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Table Template")
Set qs = Worksheets("Database Inputs")

lRow = qs.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1

ws.Range("D3").copy qs.Range("D" & lRow)
ws.Range("C8:I8").copy qs.Range("E" & lRow)
ws.Range("D13:I13").copy qs.Range("F" & lRow)
ws.Range("D11:I11").copy qs.Range("I" & lRow)
ws.Range("D21:I21").copy qs.Range("K" & lRow)
ws.Range("D12:I12").copy qs.Range("O" & lRow)
ws.Range("D15").copy qs.Range("BL" & lRow)
ws.Range("E15").copy qs.Range("BM" & lRow)
ws.Range("F15").copy qs.Range("BN" & lRow)
ws.Range("D17").copy qs.Range("BO" & lRow)
ws.Range("E17").copy qs.Range("BP" & lRow)
ws.Range("F17").copy qs.Range("BQ" & lRow)
ws.Range("D10").copy qs.Range("U" & lRow)
ws.Range("E10").copy qs.Range("V" & lRow)
End Sub
```

Comment: use `cells(row,col).value`

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: What values you want to copy to the new sheet? based on what condition? explain with an example, if possible with an image of your sheet